# Regex Javascript to get the following values : value1[value2]

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking to create a reg ex in JS that obtains 2 values from a string:

The string is always in the following format `value1[value2]`.

what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var str = "value1[value2]";
var match = str.match(/([^\[]*)\[([^\]]*)\]/);
// match = ["value1[value2]", "value1", "value2"]
```

**Explanation**

- `([^\[]*)`: capture everything until the `[` character.
- `\[`: the `[` character.
- `([^\]]*)`: capture everything until the `]` character.
- `\]`: the `]` character.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "value1[value2]";
var arr = str.split('[');

var value1 = arr[0];
var value2 = arr[1].substr(0, arr[1].length -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```javascript
function getValues(str) {
  var m = (''+str).match(/^(.*?)\[(.*?)\]$/);
  return (m) ? [m[1], m[2]] : null;
}
getValues('value1[value2]'); // => ["value1", "value2"]
getValues('foobar'); // => null
```

Of course, if you are *sure* that your input is already validated then you can simply extract values by index, which should be the fastest:

```javascript
function getValues2(str) {
  var idx = str.indexOf('[');
  return [str.substr(0, idx), str.substr(idx+1, str.length-idx-2)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think that the most readable regex expression would be something along the lines of:

```
str.match(/(.+?)([?)(.+?)(]?)/)
```

Simply returning the results you are interested in. Alexander's answer would certainly work, but I personally find excessive use of brackets and slashes to be very hard to read.

Comment: Unfortuantely this one doesn't work it returns `["value1[value2]", "value1[value2]", ""]`